# Analogy questions: acceptability and tagging

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm new to this site, and I have an idea for a question, but before I post, I want to clarify a few things.

The question I have in mind is in the format of an analogy, but it is not a typical analogy like you might see on some aptitude test (twig:branch::finger:_____), in the sense that it requires more thought and a more creative approach than a typical analogy. Looking through past questions, I have not seen many analogy based ones, so I ask: would this be an acceptable type of question for puzzlingSE?

Second, if a question of this nature was acceptable, for this one, the [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) tag definitely applies, but would a new [analogy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analogy) tag also be appropriate, since this would constitute a new format of question?

I don't really want to give away any of the question, so if I'm being too vague, just let me know, and maybe I can clarify anything.

Thank You!

Comment: With the analogy tag, I'd suggest creating it after at least 2 questions applicable for that tag have been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure it's something you think is going to be reasonably solvable, as best you can! (And if you miss the mark, don't worry; people tend to be pretty open about working with you on current or future questions. It can be helpful to ask for feedback after the fact, too!)

As far as tags go, [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) works, plus anything else you think is appropriate. I'd be reluctant to endorse a new tag specifically for analogies, because it seems (?) maybe a little broad, but it's sort of up to you.